# Laravels - Cannot Show Image after Upload and Save in Storage

Tags: laravel, image, file-upload

I will show the upload image but it shown a thumbnail,
here is my Controller Code Upload a image file

```
 $file = $request->file('images')->getClientOriginalName();
    $filename = time().$file;
    $path = base_path('/Uploads');
    if($request->hasFile('images')){
        $file = $request->file('images');
        $file->move($path, $filename);
         DB::table('books')->insert($filename);
        return redirect('home')->with('status', 'insert succesfully');
    }
    else {
        dd('Request Hash No File!');
    }
```

Here is my view

```
 @foreach ($booksDTL as $deTailsB)
     <div class="col-md-4">
       <img src="{{ asset('Uploads/'.$deTailsB->images) }}" width="100%" height="100%" title="{{ $deTailsB->images }}"/>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-6">
          <H1>{{ ucfirst(trans($deTailsB->name)) }}</H1>
          <p>{{ strtoupper($deTailsB->author) }}</p>
     </div>
@endforeach
```

Here is the controller to show data

```
public function detailBook($id)
{
    $booksdetail = DB::table('books')->where('id', $id)->get();
    return view ('details', ['booksDTL'=>$booksdetail]);
}
```

and here is when i run the code
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awe9w.png)

The upload file save into folder 'Uploads' the folder is in the out of public folder, I already run the php artisan storage:link. But the upload picture still shown in thumbnail. Do you have any suggestion to this?

Comment: `base_path('/Uploads')` indicates you have a top level folder that is a sibling to `public`. Instead, move it to `public_path('/Uploads')`. Also, the `insert->($filename)` doesn't make sense. Instead, insert it for the corresponding book entry at the appropriate ID or include the entirety of the model that needs to be saved.

Comment: oke thank you, the code works well now :) @Ohgodwhy